# How do you find variables in a terraform repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

As a beginner in terraform. I'm curious what's the ideal structure to store terraform config?

Let's say I wanted to:

1. build an ec2 instance
2. create and setup an AWS user and assign to a group

Should I write all that above in one directory?

Or is it best to split those into two parent directories on linux?

Also I have seen these big repo's with terraform code and they refer to variables. How do pro's handle reading others code? I mean is the best way to just run `grep` to see where a variable is defined, or is there a smarter way to know where (which file) a variable is hosted in.

Is there a terraform command that can list all the variables defined in a repo?

Comment: Code organization in almost any language depends on experience and nuances of the actual functionality. Variables are usually documented for modules e.g. `terraform-docs`, and so scouring the source code should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common structure would be something like this

1. stage (e.g. prod)

   1. services

      1. service-a

         1. `variables.tf`
         2. `main.tf`
         3. `...`

where you start with stages at the top level, break it down to services and there you have your `.tf` files including a `variables.tf`. The same idea applies to creating reusable infrastructure with Terraform modules.
I recommend the book [Terraform: Up and Running by Yevgeniy Brikman](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/terraform-up-and/9781098116736/). But as Matthew pointed out, it depends on your project and your experience, with Terraform you're pretty free in how you handle it.

As of my last knowledge, Terraform itself doesn't provide a direct command to list all variables defined in a repository.